# Regex to count email ids in envelope recipient

Tags: regex, email, gmail

I am a Google Apps certified consultant working on a project where client wants to restrict its senders to send email only to up to 5 recipients at a time.

Google Apps for business offers functionality of using regex; however I have very limited knowledge of regex, and I wanted to check if any of mates here can help me out.

Idea is to have a regex, which should match only if there are 6 or more recipients found in the recipients header.

Note-: above is for gmail

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to tell the user to deliminate the list somehow and then you just split the input based on the deliminators. You then check if each element is valid via standard regexs, and count them. If there are 6 or more, there is your answer.